# Generate pandas DataFrame column from list of lists of indexes using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

Here is the function I wrote to apply to each row of a df

```
def use_list_of_list_of_indexes(column1, column2):
"""
Column that contains list of lists of indices is used to generate a new column based on indices
_
Args:
column1 - list of elements
column2 - list of lists of indexes
_
Returns:
pandas.core.series.Series
"""
list_of_lists = column1.apply(lambda row: [[row[i] for i in x] for x in column2])
return list_of_lists
```

Here is df

```
col1                     col2
[55, 475,243,60]         [[0,1,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

When using

```
df['col3'] = use_list_of_list_of_indexes(df.col1, df.col2)
```

I want to get

```
col3
[[55, 475, 243], [55, 475, 60], [55, 243, 60], [475, 243, 60]]
```

However, I get error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Adding `[0]` to `df.col2` solves the problem, but how should I rewrite use_list_of_list_of_indexes function to be able to apply it to the whole column?

```
df['col3'] = use_list_of_list_of_indexes(df.col1, df.col2[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do it this way you are missing one loop:

```
column1.apply(lambda row: [[[row[z] for z in y] for y in x] for x in column2])
```

x gives you `[[0,1,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,3], [1,2,3]]`

y gives you `[0,1,2]`

so you have to use `z` to iterate over `y`

To do it in a slightly better way:

```
df['col3'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda r: [[r['col1'][y] for y in x] for x in r['col2']], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Is there a better way to solve my problem other than list comprehensions?

Comment: I don't see a better way to do it in one line so far, but I think it is possible to reduce one loop

Comment: Can you comment why edited version is better in your opinion?

Comment: because I feel what you actually want is: for each item in column 1, iterate it over the index in the corresponding row of column 2. It seems your function is doing it for all the rows in column 2